# Silverlight MP3 Playing Library

Tags: silverlight, audio

I'm trying to play MP3 files in SilverSprite, and it's super buggy. Is there an alternative library I can use to play MP3s in Silverlight?

**Edit:** Now that there's a bounty, I'm specifically looking for something that:

- Works with SL 3-4
- Is a separate project/DLL
- Will work in SilverSprite projects (I'm using a layer on top of SS) -- no GUI, just methods I can call to play sounds
- Works with content that has the build action set to `Content`. **I cannot use embedded resources** due to a bug in SilverSprite. My app will not run.
- Plays MP3s.
- Can play multiple audio files at the same time

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to find. I would like something I can embed in my own game engine, which sits on top of SilverSprite. I will supply all the audio files in the XAP. (The SilverSprite audio is quite broken and doesn't work.)

**Update:** The specific direction I would probably like to go in is to instantiate a new MediaElement, set the source, and play it. I have some code below, but a) `NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` reports 0, and b) the `.MediaOpened` never triggers.

```
MediaElement m = new MediaElement();
m.Source = new Uri("Content/Audio/chimes.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
m.Stop(); // useless?
//m.SetSource(new FileStream("Content/Audio/chimes.mp3", FileMode.Open)); // "Permission denied" exception, is it even finding the file?
m.Volume = 1; // Max
m.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
while (m.CurrentState != System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Closed)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
m.MediaOpened += (sender, e) =>
{
    m.Play();
};
m.Play();
```

Answer (score 1):

For some working code rather similar to your updated approach see http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/577 . Beware that the `MediaElement` needs to be added to the control/component tree - see http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/12/17/playing-sound-effects-on-windows-phone-7/.

Two very interesting options for your requirements is [this library](http://salusemediakit.codeplex.com/) and [this one](http://vorbisplayer.codeplex.com/).

For this kind of stuff you could also implement/use a custom [`MediaStreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource%28VS.95%29.aspx) like [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers) one... see [here](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/579) and [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/01/mediastreamsource-sample-with-source-code.aspx).

EDIT - some other options:

Playing multiple sounds in parallel via XNA see source code at http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/silverlightsound

Using MediaPlayer class from XNA 4 for example:

```
MediaPlayer.Stop();
MediaPlayer.Volume = 1;
MediaPlayer.Play(Song.FromUri("TestSound", new Uri("/Content/Audio/chimes.mp3", UriKind.Relative)));
```

As for playing multiple sound files at the same time:

IIRC this is something which could cause your app to fail validation.

Comment: I'll look at the links. Fail which validation? I don't have a component tree; only a single component for my game.

Comment: App validation isn't an issue, since this will be playable via the web. Are you interested in looking at my source? I tried a couple of the sources above, but either get an empty resource or nothing happening.

Comment: @ashes999 I can try (depends on how much source that is)

Comment: Thanks for your help. None of these options work; I think the problem is that my XNA implementation (SilverSprite) is a piece of .... so methods don't exist or don't work. Cheers, I appreciate the effort you put into researching all these options. Maybe they will come in useful for someone someday.